# Telerik mvc treeview refresh query

Tags: treeview, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerikmvc treeview refresh question. I need to refresh the treeview after updating a partial view.

My javascript function to refresh the grid is -

```
  var item = $("#TreeView").find(".t-input[name='itemValue'][value='" + Id + "']").closest("li");
                $("#TreeView").data("tTreeView").ajaxRequest(item);
```

I get "no element found" javascript error.

Menu View -

```
@(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("TreeView")
    .ShowLines(false)
        .ClientEvents(events => events
                    .OnSelect("onSelect"))
    .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
    {
        mappings.For<Model>(binding => binding
                .ItemDataBound((item, products) =>
                {
                    item.Text = products.Name;
                    item.Value = products.Id.ToString();
                    item.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/project_icon.jpg";
                    item.LoadOnDemand = true;
                })
          )
        }
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

I created a PartialView "Menu". Controller code to return the partial view is

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        return PartialView("Menu", GetAllProducts());
   }
```

Jquery code to update a product and refresh the treeview -

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    success: function (data) {

         **Refresh the tree view**
         $.get('/Menu/Index').done(function (data) {
            $("#leftnav").html($(data));
        });

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error updating for  Id : " + id);
    }
});
```

}